# Next lexicographically bigger string permutation and solution efficiency

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve Hackerrank question: Find next lexicographically bigger string permutation for a given string input.

Here my solution:

```
def biggerIsGreater(w):

    if len(w)<=1: return w

    # pair letters in w string with int representing positional index in alphabet
    letter_mapping = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, range(1, len(string.ascii_lowercase)+1)))

    char_ints = [letter_mapping[letter] for letter in w.lower() if letter in letter_mapping]

    # reverse it
    reversed_char_ints = char_ints[::-1]

    # get char set to reorder, including pivot.
    scanned_char_ints = []
    index = 0
    zipped = list(zip(reversed_char_ints, reversed_char_ints[1:]))
    while index < len(zipped):
        char_tuple = zipped[index]
        scanned_char_ints.append(char_tuple[0])
        if char_tuple[0] <= char_tuple[1]:
            if index == len(zipped) - 1:
                return "no answer"
        else:
            scanned_char_ints.append(char_tuple[1])
            break
        index += 1

    # get smallest among bigger values of pivot
    char_to_switch = None
    char_to_switch_index = None
    for item in scanned_char_ints[:-1]:
        if item > scanned_char_ints[-1]:
            if char_to_switch == None or item <= char_to_switch:
                char_to_switch = item
                char_to_switch_index = scanned_char_ints.index(item)

    # switch pivot and smallest of bigger chars in scanned chars
    pivot_index = len(scanned_char_ints) - 1
    scanned_char_ints[pivot_index], scanned_char_ints[char_to_switch_index] = scanned_char_ints[char_to_switch_index], scanned_char_ints[pivot_index]

    # order from second to end the other chars, so to find closest bigger number of starting number
    ord_scanned_char_ints = scanned_char_ints[:-1]
    ord_scanned_char_ints.sort(reverse=True)
    ord_scanned_char_ints.append(scanned_char_ints[-1])

    # reverse scanned chars
    ord_scanned_char_ints.reverse()

    # rebuild char int list
    result_ints = char_ints[:len(char_ints) - len(ord_scanned_char_ints)]

    result_ints.extend(ord_scanned_char_ints)

    result_ = ""
    for char_intx in result_ints:
        for char, int_charz in letter_mapping.items():
            if int_charz == char_intx:
                result_ += char
    return result_
```

(I know that there are solution on internet with more concise way of implement the problem, but I obviously trying to succeed by myself).
Now, it seems to run for 1, 2, 100 input of strings with at most 100 characters.
But when hackerrank test procedure tests it against 100000 strings of at most 100 letters, an error results, with no further information about it. Running a test with a similar input size, in my machine, does not throw any error.

What is wrong with this solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this about finding the next lexicographically larger *permutation* of the letters in the string?

Comment: Yes. I should return the smallest lexicographically higher string possible from the given string ( a set of strings), or no answer.